# Casteo de numeros con punto decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen día a todos, hoy estoy intentando redondear un valor de tipo ***FLOAT*** a dos decimales pero al hacerlo mediante la consulta en ***SQL SERVER*** que se muestra abajo, algunos valores me los redondea de forma correcta y otros no, ejemplo: *19.1 me lo redondea a 19.10* ya con los dos dígitos y *18.4 me lo muestra como 18.39* saben a que se debe o conocen un mejor método de hacerlo, de nuevo gracias a todos por su ayuda.

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND(tc_precio, 2, 1) AS DECIMAL (18, 2)) FROM Tipo_Cambio
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En realidad, ni siquiera necesitas el `ROUND`. Si lo quitas completamente, el `ROUND` se hace automáticamente al hacer el cast a `DECIMAL(18, 2)`:

```
SELECT CAST(tc_precio AS DECIMAL (18, 2))
  FROM Tipo_Cambio
```

Answer (score 2):

Debes hacerlo de esta forma:

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND(tc_cambio, 2) AS DECIMAL (18, 2)) FROM Tipo_Cambio
```

Solo es de quitar el tercer parámetro de `ROUND`.

Comment: Si el valor insertado en el campo tc_cambio viene con esta nomenclatura, 18.4 es posible hacerlo?

Comment: Ah si, se me olvidó dejar la variable

Answer (score 2):

En lugar de `CAST` utiliza `CONVERT`

Por ejemplo, el siguiente código genera los resultados **19.10** y **18.40**

```
DECLARE @varFloat1 AS FLOAT
DECLARE @varFloat2 AS FLOAT

SET @varFloat1 = 19.1
SET @varFloat2 = 18.4

SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL (18, 2), @varFloat1)
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL (18, 2), @varFloat2)
```